# asynchronous function result in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

warning : this question tries to be general so I use pseudo-code. It's more about a technique than an actual solution to a very specific problem.

My issue is that I have a function that does multiple async calls to a server to gather information and I want to use the result of that function in another function. How does one temporize until the results are actually there ?

Pseudo-code example :

```
var getsomething = function(objs) {

    var results = objs.map(getsomethingforoneobj);

    $.when.apply(this,results).done(function() {
        var result;
        for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            //do something with the data to augment the variable 'result'
        }
        console.log("load finished");
        console.log(result);
        return result;
    });
}

var getsomethingforoneobj = function(obj) {
    var url = "blabla"
    return $.ajax({
        async:true,
        url:url,
        success : function(data) {
            return data;
        }
    });
}

$(function() {
    var myobjs = [{},{},{},...]
    var a = getsomething(myobjs); //this is where I would want to temporize
    var b = a_function_of_a(a);
    //use b in the rest of the code
});
```

One solution would obviously be to do everything in an synchronous manner but I've learnt it's very bad form.

All help welcome !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend [async waterfall](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#waterfall) for your scenario.

But if you don't want to import external libraries you could check out this function [Finalize](http://www.catalinmunteanu.com/finalize-javascript-asynchronous-requests-queue/) that allows you to queue hooks and to execute a function when all the hooks were removed from the q.

For your case it could be something like:

```
...
$(function() {

    var a = null;
    var b = null;
    var myobjs = [{},{},{},...]

    var req_set = new Finalize(function() {
        console.log(a, b);
    });

    var hook1 = req_set.queue();
    getsomething(myobjs, function(err, res) {
        a = res
        hook1();
    }); //this is where I would want to temporize

    var hook2 = req_set.queue();
    a_function_of_a(a, function(err, res) {
        b = res;
        hook2();
    });

    req_set.exec();

});
```

I also changed your functions to [Error-First Callback](http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/03/understanding-error-first-callbacks-in-node-js/)

Comment: i'm perfectly happy using external libraries - will have a look at async as well as `q` as pointed out by Mohit below.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some kind of promises to solve this.

[q.js](https://github.com/kriskowal/q)

This is one if the libraries that makes use of promises and keeps state of function calls while they are still asyn. They even have different calls when error is returned and success is returned